# Operator Precedence Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, compiler-construction, evaluation, operator-precedence

I am currently writing a compiler for a custom programming language. The compiler converts *every* single operator or call to an object of the form

```
Call : Value
{
  Value instance
  String name
  Value[] arguments
}
```

For example, the expression `3 + 4` (= `3.+(4)`) becomes

```
Call : Value
{
  instance = Value(3)
  name = "+"
  arguments = [ Value(4) ]
}
```

The expression `3 + 4 * 5` would be evaluated by the parser as `3.+(4).*(5)`.

```
Call : Value
{
  instance = Call
             {
               instance = Value(3)
               name = "+"
               arguments = Value(4)
             }
  name = "*"
  arguments = [ Value(5) ]
}
```

I know have a function that creates a list of the calls in this structure and sorts them by operator precedence, and the result would look like this:

`[ 3.+(4).*(5), 3.+(4) ]` (in the above form)

What I need now is an algorithm that sorts them so that the first expression is `3.+(4.*(5))`. The problem about this is that the result from above can have any length. My current implementation (which relies on it being 2 or less infix operators) does it like this:

```
(go through all elements)
{
  current.arguments = [ prev ]
  prev.instance = current.arguments[0]
}
```

I know that operator precedence is usually achieved with special constructs in BNF files for parser generation, but since I am using a custom parser that will always evaluate this left-to-right, I cannot use such solutions.

Comment: Take a look at the shunting-yard algorithm.

Comment: I'd also consider learning a parser generator tool like ANTLR, so you can delegate this functionality to the parser

Comment: I don't believe that is possible, as the grammar of the programming language is too complicated to be fully representable in a grammar file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common solution is an algorithm sometimes called the "shunting yard", which uses an operator stack.

- push mark on stack at lowest priority
- get a primary
- get an operator
- if the precedence is lower or no more operators, pop the stack and generate code
- push the operator on the stack
- loop until the mark is all that is left

I'm sure you'll find a better explanation, but that's how I do it.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my parser system and it kind of works now, without the need to do some complex sorting and other wasteful operations.

Comment: I'm glad it works but you don't fill me with confidence. Maybe you should post your solution in the form of a new question.

Comment: You can view the source file with the solution here: https://github.com/Clashsoft/Dyvil/blob/master/src/main/java/dyvil/tools/compiler/parser/expression/ExpressionParser.java (line 280 and 361)